# Delete rows with specific values

Tags: excel, powershell, delete-row

I'm using this part of my script to delete each row where there is value : admin

```
$i = 1

Do {
    If ($worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value() -eq 'admin') 
      {
            $objRange = $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 5).EntireRow
            $objRange.Delete()
        $i -= 1 
      }
      $i += 1
}

While ($worksheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Value() -ne $null)
```

I would like to know how can I add some different values and delete more rows with words like : system, computer ...

Thanks !

Comment: I see that you are doing `$i -= 1` in order to delete duplicates. That's a good idea, but an even better one is to run from the end back to the beginning. Why is that better? Well, in most cases you say something like "from start_index to end_index" and when you delete entries, your "end_index" might go over the boundaries. While working from end back to beginning "end_index back to start_index", you will never get in trouble with the boundaries.

Comment: one way would be to use the `-in` operator to see if the `.Value()` string is in a list on the other side of the operator. take a look at `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-in` collection containment operators:

```
$rowValuesToDelete = 'admin','system','computer'

if($worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value() -in $rowValuesToDelete) {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I need !